# Does this code with many when & then pairs works?

Tags: oracle

My code is as below. It looks funny, though, because of many `when` and `then` statements. Does this code return some value?

The returned value should be `'32E1.85T'`. And, is it correct that there is a limit of number of `when` and  `pair`? Is the limit is 255?

```
WITH materialtype AS ( SELECT  CASE  
                                                        WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'C' THEN 'C'
                                                     WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+11,1)= 'N' THEN 'C'                        
                                                     WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'C' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'O' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'D' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'L' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Z' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Y' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'E' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'F' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'R' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'W' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '1' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '2' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '3' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '4' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '5' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '6' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'A' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'B' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '7' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '8' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'N' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'C' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '9' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'D' THEN 'C'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'E' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'M' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'P' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'W' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'F' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Q' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Y' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'R' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'S' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'G' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'H' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'T' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'U' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'I' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'J' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'V' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'K' THEN 'E'
WHEN  SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'L' THEN 'E'                        

                                             ELSE 'fff'
                                END  
               FROM DUAL )
,modeltype AS (
                         SELECT   CASE  

WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+1,2)= '03' THEN  CASE WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+12,1)= 'B' THEN 'THMC'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Z' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Y' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'R' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'W' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '225' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='C'  THEN '225'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '105' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='C'  THEN '105'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,1)= 'R' THEN ' low'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+5,1)= 'R' THEN ' low'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,1)= '0' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+5,1)<= 9 THEN ' low'    END 
WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+1,2)= '05' THEN  CASE WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+12,1)= 'B' THEN 'THMC'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+11,1)= 'W' THEN '3'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '106' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Z' THEN '106'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '106' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Y' THEN '106'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '106' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'R' THEN '106'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '106' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'W' THEN '106'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '226' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Z' THEN '226'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '226' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Y' THEN '226'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '226' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'R' THEN '226'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '226' AND SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'W' THEN '226'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Z' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'Y' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'R' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+13,1)= 'W' THEN ''
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '475' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='C'  THEN '475'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+4,3)= '106' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='C'  THEN '106'    END 
WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+1,2)= '31' THEN  CASE WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '9' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'C' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'E' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'F' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'M' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'P' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'H' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'T' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'H' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='U'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'H' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='I'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'J' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'V' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'K' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'L' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.85T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= '9' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'G' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'S' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'R' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Y' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Q' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'D' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.35T'    END 
WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+1,2)= '32' THEN  CASE WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'C' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'E' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'F' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'M' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'P' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'H' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'T' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'U' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'I' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'J' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'K' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'L' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.8T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'G' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'S' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'R' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Y' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'Q' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'
                                                                           WHEN SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+9,1)= 'D' AND  (SELECT * FROM materialtype)='E'  THEN '1.34T'    END 




             ELSE 'dadf'
                     END  
           FROM DUAL ) SELECT SUBSTR('CL32______Q___E',2+1,2 ) || (SELECT * FROM materialtype)  ||  (SELECT * FROM modeltype) FROM DUAL
```

Comment: So what happens when you run it? This query also selects data from tables nobody else is going to have (e.g. MATERIALTYPE, MODELTYPE) so nobody else can test it. Run it and find out what you get. Best of luck.

Comment: Haven't you tested it yet ? It worked like a cham and returned `32E1.34T`. But I think it can be safely replaced by simple: `SELECT '32E1.34T' FROM dual`

Comment: @BobJarvis - it's only using DUAL; the two you mention are CTEs. It's horrible and pointless but does run stand-alone.

Comment: What is the point of breaking down a fixed value like this? Or will you be using a variable at some point - in which case it could still be simplified (or at least made shorter). Also, [from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm), "The maximum number of arguments in a CASE expression is 65535. All expressions count toward this limit, including the initial expression of a simple CASE expression and the optional ELSE expression. Each WHEN ... THEN pair counts as two arguments." So don't know where you got 255 from.

Comment: I think it is better to create look up tables to map sub strings to values and then do joins. So many case statements is tough to read.

Comment: there is no mutable row source involved (DUAL and two CTEs). why is the first argument to SUBSTR always the same string constant? Is that some kind of dynamically genereated script? If so, the logic for it would be placed better in the code that generates it, because it will do nothing but happily consume CPU cycles until it returns a short constant string?